# Physical keyboard samsung trio + enter key + viber

Tags: keyboard, viber-messenger

I have a problem  with my physical keyboard samsung trio when i use viber. When I press the Enter key, changes line, instead of sending the message. This does not happen in facebook messenger. Is a matter of viber?

Thank you!

Comment: I've never used Viber, but yes, [an app can customize the enter button](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style#Action). Is there a setting inside the app regarding the behavior of the enter key?

Comment: Yes there is, but concerns the behavior of the mobile/tablet keyboard, not the physical keyboard. This setting enabled doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and figured it out. If you're using the Samsung Smart KBD Trio 500 to type text messages you have to press **Alt+Enter** to send the message within the phone messaging app. I don't know if this works for all texting/messaging platforms but this does work with the default Samsung phone keyboard in the Samsung messages app.